Change gravity level in Star Trek Voyager Elite Force
I would like to change the default gravity level in Star Trek: Voyager - Elite Force, so that I can jump higher in mission 6.1.  I can't manage to jump onto the final platform.
Any help would be appreciated.

A simpler solution would to use the noclip cheat and fly yourself over the jump

Use the noclip cheat command.
Hit the ~ (tilde) button on your keyboard and type noclip into the window that comes up.
Note that this won't work in multiplayer mode. Also, you may need to type in sv_cheats 1 if cheats aren't activated.
To deactivate cheats once active, bring up the command window again and type in sv_cheats 0.
Source

Thank you noclip worked fine.

@user354676 If the answer worked for you, would you also consider upvoting my answer? Thanks!
